# "Production CSID does not cover Simplified documents" error while submitting simplified invoice into ZATCA

Tags: python, csr

I'm trying to use zatca sdk to generate the CSR using our company information with a valid VAT number and the default OTP provided by Fatoora "123345", then i could generate the CSID and PCSID, i also singed the invoice with the CSID certificate and generate the hash and qr code fot it, i submitted to compliance and it was passed, but when try to submit it to reporting using the the PCSID for authentication and CSID or PCSID for signing it, it also always says:

```
{
  "res": {
    "validationResults": {
      "infoMessages": [
        {
          "type": "INFO",
          "code": "XSD_ZATCA_VALID",
          "category": "XSD validation",
          "message": "Complied with UBL 2.1 standards in line with ZATCA specifications",
          "status": "PASS"
        }
      ],
      "warningMessages": [],
      "errorMessages": [
        {
          "type": "ERROR",
          "code": "certificate-permissions",
          "category": "CERTIFICATE_ERRORS",
          "message": "Production CSID does not cover Simplified documents",
          "status": "ERROR"
        }
      ],
      "status": "ERROR"
    },
    "reportingStatus": "NOT_REPORTED"
  }
}
```

code for submitting to reporting

```
def reporting_API(uuid1, hash_value, signed_xmlfile_name, invoice_number, sales_invoice_doc ):
    sdk_settings = SDKSettings.objects.get(id=0)
    payload = load_api_request()
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-language": "en",
        "Clearance-Status": "1",
        "Accept-Version": "V2",
        "Authorization": "Basic" + sdk_settings.basic_auth_production,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cookie": "TS0106293e=0132a679c0639d13d069bcba831384623a2ca6da47fac8d91bef610c47c7119dcdd3b817f963ec301682dae864351c67ee3a402866",
    }
    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        url=get_API_url(base_url="invoices/reporting/single"),
        headers=headers,
        data=payload,
    )
```

i also put the certificate and private key in the SDK data certificate folder.

Tried to use CSID and PCSID, tried to use some default values recommended by this website but it couldn't help:
https://www.apizatca.com/post/resolving-production-csid-error-zatca-e-invoicing

Comment: I am no expert, but from error message "Production CSID does not cover Simplified documents" it seems like the document you are submitting doesn't satisfy the requirements for Production CSID.  Without further information see [mre], it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, when i try to test via the XML validation provided by zatca, it says:

Errors
category : SIGNATURE_ERROR
code :X509IssuerName
message : wrong X509IssuerName  
category : SIGNATURE_ERROR
code :X509SerialNumber
message : wrong X509SerialNumber  

I suspect the OTP that i'm using is causing the issue, because it's 123345, maybe if got one from fatoora portal (in which i don't have access now) it could solve the problem,
It's the same issue is giving when i try to upload the simplified invoice on their SDK examples

Answer (score 0):

it seems that when you generate CSID you have to select either simplified invoice / standard invoice or both in title parameter. 1100 represents both. 1000 only standard and 0100 only simplified

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue is because of the sandbox env that I'm using, On Sandbox it's always going to return a static PCSID that doesn't correspond to your generated CSID, and it doesn't also work with simplified invoices if you want to send simplified invoices to compliance, then you'll need to move to a simulation env where you'll use a valid OTPs to get the CSID then the PCSID if you want to send to reporting then move to production.